# Finding a minimum scaling factor for rectangle so that inner rectangles don't go beyond certain value

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algorithms, ratio

I need to find a ratio for a rectangle bound such that the rectangles enclosed within that are not less than a preset value, say 20 unit. 
[figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWse1.png)

I should be able to scale the black rectangle only uniformly (both x and y axis together) and the rectangles within the box should scale appropriately. but the catch is that, when we reduce the scale of the bounding rectangle it should stop at a value where the smallest rectangle inside the the bounding rectangle is not less than 20 units (height or length, whichever is longer). I need to find the minimum scale ratio for the outer rectangle such that , the ratio will prevent the smallest rectangle's length or width(whichever is largest) from going below 20

for example, if the minimum scale ratio of the rectangle = 0.5 , the rectangle can't be scaled below 50% of it's largest side.
I need to find the minimum scale ratio of the black rectangle so that it prevents the smallest rectangle from going below 20 units.

So far i have done like,
`selection` is the black rectangle

`selectionScaleValue = Math.max(selection.width, selection.height)`

also finds the smallest rectangle within the bounding rectangle, but i have no luck with the addressed issue.
I currently fetches the

- selection rectangle height and width
- the smallest rectangle's height
  and width
- minimum size for the inner rectangle till it can down
  scaled (20 units)

I need to find the minimum scale ratio of the black rectangle so that it prevents the smallest rectangle from going below 20 units.

Comment: 1. Find longest side of each inner rectangle. 2. Find minimum of length of sides found in 1. 3. If this length is $a\geq 20$, then minimum scaling ratio is $\frac{20}{a}$. If length found in 2 is less than 20, then you need scale up to increase it to 20 and scaling factor is $\frac{20}{a}$ again.

Comment: surprised that actually worked! I always thought it would be depended on dimensions of the outer rectangle. thank you!